# Nested UIScrollViews with horizontal scrolling for both

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a nested `UIScrollView` inside another one, both are horizontal.

The outer one contains multiple `UIScrollViews`, let's say one per page (of a document with multiple pages). 
The inner one can contain just a `UIView` that fits the screen or maybe some bigger `UIView` that should be scrolled too (tipically horizontally, but if the user pinches the screen, then he could scroll in both directions).

The problem occurs when I fastly scroll the document and the outer scroll view just decides to scroll its subviews, without letting the inner scroll views (those whose contentSize is bigger than the screen size) scroll at all. 
If I gently scroll the outer scroll view, it instead lets the inner one scroll too.

The desired behavior is that even if I fastly scroll the outer scroll view, it should scroll the inner one, until its content has been completely shown and only then let the outer scroll view scroll.

I tried overriding `hitTest:withEvent:` so that the outer scroll view should ask its currently visible `UIScrollView` subview if it should scroll or not, but this currently only works when scrolling forward. The problem is that I can't detect scrolling direction in `hitTest:withEvent:`, so I'm also thinking about moving this code into somewhere else, but I don't know if it's the correct way to go.

I'm sorry for all the "scroll" word in the sentences, but I don't know how to explain this in a better way

Comment: scrollview inside scrollview is not a recommended pattern by apple.It can bring unpredictable results

Comment: here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/NestedScrollViews/NestedScrollViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH7-SW2 they say it's supported. Unfortunately I can't see any other way to accomplish this. Moreover, I'm working on a big code base and it's unlikely that we're going to refactor this unless that's the only option

Comment: It also says ***Note: This same-direction scrolling is supported, and there is a distinct behavior defined for the functionality, however that behavior is subject to change in future versions of iOS.***

Answer (score 0):

If the outer scrollView still animates movement, it will get all gestures instead of letting inner one handle them.

You could try using gestureRecognizer's requireGestureRecognizerToFail: method, so that panGestureRecognizer of the outer scroll view requires panGestureRecognizers of the outer scrollViews to fail. It might make the scrolling feel a bit laggy, and I'm not sure if that'll solve your problem but hey, doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: I implemented your suggested solution. Everything works as expected, but now of course scrolling only happens when I lift my finger. This is counterintuitive and yet I think that it cannot be fixed if implemented this way.

Comment: I had a similiar problem in one of my apps, but I was supposed to make the outer scroll view only react to 2-finger scrolling. So I just disabled panGestureRecognizer in inner scrollViews and added UISwipeGestureRecognizers to move left and right, runs smooth now. If limiting outer scrolling to 2-fingers gestures and some kind of paging in inner views is acceptable in your app, you could try that.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't introduce 2-fingers gestures because the user interaction has to be the same. I'll try to refactor the outer scroll view class to add the possibility of managing double-pages as single pages by increasing the frame size of particular pages so that I actually won't ever need scroll the inner scroll views.